# Failed to build Boost.Build engine

Tags: c++, boost

I was trying to build boost (1_65_0) engine by writing 'bootstrap' to visual studio command prompt 2010 and I go this error.. any suggestions?

here is a part of the bootstrap.log :

```
###
### Using 'vc10' toolset.
###

c:\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 

c:\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap 

c:\boost_1_65_0\tools\build\src\engine>cl /nologo /RTC1 /Zi /MTd /Fobootstrap/ /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG -wd4996 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c 
command.c
compile.c
variable.c
modules.c
strings.c
strings.c(195) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
strings.c(196) : error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
strings.c(196) : error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
strings.c(196) : warning C4047: '>=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
strings.c(196) : error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
strings.c(196) : error C2100: illegal indirection
strings.c(196) : error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
strings.c(196) : error C2100: illegal indirection
strings.c(196) : error C2065: 'p' : undeclared identifier
strings.c(196) : error C2100: illegal indirection
strings.c(196) : error C2106: '=' :
```

Comment: I reproduced the failure with Visual Studio 2010. Visual Studio 2013 was able to bootstrap.

Comment: Most likely you can use the bjam created with a new compiler. I remember doing that in the past when I built my code with multiple compilers.

Comment: My above comment seems to be working. I ran bootstrap from VS2013 but now I am able to build boost using VS2010.